# Is the map $A \to \bigwedge^{k}A $ from matrices above rank $k$ proper?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, determinants, real-algebraic-geometry, exterior-algebra

$\newcommand{\End}{\operatorname{End}}$

Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional **real** vector space. ($d \ge 3$). Fix an **odd** $2 \le k \le d-1$. Define
$H_{>k}=\{ A \in \End(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) > k 
\}$. $H_{>k}$ is an open submanifold of $\End(V)$.

We also define, for a given number $s$, the open submanifold

$$\tilde H_{>s}=\{ B \in \End(\bigwedge^k V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(B) > s 
\} \subseteq \End(\bigwedge^k V).$$

Consider the map
$$
\psi:H_{>k} \to \tilde H_{>k} \, \,, \, \, \psi(A)=\bigwedge^{k}A,
%\psi:H_r \to \text{End}(\bigwedge^{k}V) \, \,, \, \, \psi(A)=\bigwedge^{k}A,
$$

$\psi$ is a **smooth injective immersion**. (The injectivity uses the fact $k$ is odd, since otherwise $\psi(A)=\psi(-A)$).

> **Question:** Is $\psi$ is a proper map?

(In the case $k=d-1$, the answer is positive, since then we ask if $\psi:\text{GL}(V) \to \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k V) $ is proper. See more details below).

*Explanation on the codomain of $\psi$:*

Let $H_{i}=\{ A \in \End(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) = i 
\}$, and $\tilde H_i$ its analog on the exterior algebra $\bigwedge^kV$.

For $A \in \text{End}(V)$,
 $$\operatorname{rank}(\bigwedge^kA) = \binom {\operatorname{rank}(A)}{k} ,$$  that is $\psi(H_r) \subseteq \tilde H_{\binom {r}{k}}$.

In particular, this implies $\psi(H_{>k}) \subseteq \tilde H_{>k}$.

**I know that each restriction $\psi|_{H_r}:H_r \to H_{\binom {r}{k}}$ is proper**, but I am having trouble with handling the case where the domain is the union $H_{>k}=\cup_{i=k+1}^d H_i$.

*In particular, I am not sure about the following related sub-question:*

Let $A_n \in H_{>k}$, and suppose that $\psi(A_n)=\bigwedge^k A_n$ converges to some $D \in 
\tilde H_{>k}$. Is it true that $D \in \tilde H_{\binom {i}{k}}$ for some $i>k$? (We can assume all the $A_n$'s have the same rank, hence all the $\psi(A_n)$ also have the same rank. In general, the rank of the limit $D$ can fall below the shared rank of the $\psi(A_n)$. The question is if it must fall to another "legal" value, which is one of the values that are obtainable from endomorphisms of $V$).

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the link with your recent question https://mathoverflow.net/q/302071 .

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for your answer there... I was actually aware of the different ranks phenomena, but somehow forgot about it. The whole situation is slightly confusing, but the important point seems to be specifying the domain and codomain carefully...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative:

Let $d=4,k=2$: Let $A_n=\text{diag}(n,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) \in \text{End}( V)$. (We choose a basis and let $A_n$ be diagonal w.r.t this basis).

Then $\bigwedge^2 A_n =\text{diag}(1,1,1,\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{n^2}) \in \text{End}( \bigwedge^2 V)$ converges to $D=\text{diag}(1,1,1,0,0,0) \in \tilde H_3$.

Note that in this case we consider $\psi$ as a map 
$$ \psi:H_{>2}= H_3 \cup H_4 \to \tilde H_{>2}=\tilde H_3 \cup \tilde H_4 \cup \tilde H_5 \cup \tilde H_6.$$

Define $K=\{\bigwedge^2 A_n\}\cup D \subseteq \tilde H_{>2}$. $K$ is compact, but $A_n \in \psi^{-1}(K)$ does not contain a convergent subsequence in $H_{>2}$, so $\psi^{-1}(K)$ is not compact.

This shows the map $\psi$, as defined with the given domain and co-domain, is not proper. I required $k$ to be odd, but this example can be easily adapted to the odd case.

---

*Indeed, here is an example for the case $k$ is odd:*

Set $d=5,k=3$:

$A_n=\text{diag}(n,\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\frac{1}{ \sqrt n},\frac{1}{ \sqrt n},\frac{1}{ \sqrt n}) \in \text{End}( V)$.

Then $\bigwedge^3 A_n =\text{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3},\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3},\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3},\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3}) \in \text{End}( \bigwedge^3 V)$ converges to $D=\text{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0) \in \tilde H_6 \subseteq \tilde H_{>3}$.

Note that in this case we consider $\psi$ as a map 
$$ \psi:H_{>3}\to \tilde H_{>3}.$$

Define $K=\{\bigwedge^3 A_n\}\cup D \subseteq \tilde H_{>3}$. $K$ is compact, but $A_n \in \psi^{-1}(K)$ does not contain a convergent subsequence in $H_{>3}$, so $\psi^{-1}(K)$ is not compact.